# how to read all keys in appengine memcache?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I put a bunch of keys/values in the memcache. Now I want to read all keys/values from the memcache, is there any way with java to do that using any library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcache in general and Google App Engine Memcache in particular have no mechanisms for iterating through the keys/values.   If you have a particularly hot key it will be available at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/memcache, but otherwise you will need to iterate through the set of keys you believe you might have stored.